# Is it possible to create a python script which is to be run in an android phone, for doing certain tasks automatically?

Tags: python, android, android-studio, appium, python-appium

I am asking you whether, it is possible to proceed like this.

1. First, the UI elements of the app, is identified (using Appium,
   Android Studio).
2. The python script is created based on this - `Test.py`
3. This file (Test.py) is copied to android phone.
4. This is run on android phone, using apps which can run python scripts. Thus automation of tasks is done in the phone.

When this python script is run using apps like QPython, (on android phone) it should click on UI elements automatically and do different tasks as mentioned below :

1. Open Quora app.
2. "Click on Settings ->  Click on Sounds -> Click on Phone Ringtone".

I don't know much about python language and android automation.

Comment: Maybe read [this](https://www.impigertech.com/resources/blogs/android-ui-automation). It's designed to run test cases in Python on Android phones. These test cases can interact with the user interface.

Comment: Thank you! I think it will help me. I'll try this.